# What causes sub-second mains voltage outages?

Tags: power, power-engineering

Many times I observed a following electrical event: mains voltage will suddenly drop and then immediately restore. This causes lights to blink and computers to restart.

I can't imaging what could cause such a short event. I mean if someone wants to open a switch on a substation (or somewhere else in the grid) they do it for some service operation that takes time, so it doesn't make sense to have an outage shorter than several dozen seconds. So to me it looks like electrical company servicemen just open a switch and then close it to play an evil joke on the customers.

What causes such short mains outages?

Comment: "just open a switch and then close it to play an evil joke on the customers"...hilarious!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If someone turns ON a large load (my table saw does this), it will cause the mains voltage to sag for a second or three and then it recovers while the load is still on.  There are several reasons for this.  Here they are, in rough order of decreasing probability:

1. Many devices consume the highest power immediately after power-on and then quickly settle down to something normal.  This is sometimes called "inrush current", but in a table saw this is "startup current".  If the power distribution wires have lots of resistance due to length or corrosion then this effect will be worse.
2. The power distribution wires also have inductance.  If the inductance is large and someone turns on a large load (without inrush/startup current) then you could see a similar effect where the mains voltage dips for a few moments.
3. Someone turns on a large load and the voltage dips, the power company notices this and adjusts it's output voltage to compensate.  This one is a weird one because depending on where you are relative to the power company and the load you might actually see the lights get brighter rather than dimmer!
4. There is a "disturbance" in the power company and they have to switch from one power source to another.  Normally this isn't a problem, but mistakes do happen.

Comment: Yeah, my table saw does the same thing even though it draws well less than the 200 A the house service is rated for.

Comment: Interesting - we see the same thing on occasion - well, hear it, actually: our CO detector chirps on power-downs and power-ups, and the stove or u-wave clocks will reset.  We won't have started or stopped any equipment; a 1500W space heater and the oil-burner motor are about all we have, and those cycle way more frequently than we we ever witness glitches.  And even when we do occasionally overload and trip a breaker on the kitchen or bathroom, we don't glitch the clocks. I've always assumed glitches came from outside. Sgl family home rewired 40yr ago w/ circuit breakers & GFIs as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question depends upon how low your voltage goes, and how long it stays that way.

Previous answers have addressed the case of "voltage dips but not to 0" and "lasts for under 2 seconds".

However, if you are referring to situations where your voltage does drop to 0 and it stays that way for somewhere between 3 and 6 seconds, you are probably looking at the operation of an [automatic recloser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recloser). These are essentially circuit breakers on power lines which, after they trip, wait a few seconds and try turning back on again in case the fault (for instance, a tree branch shorting out a set of power lines) has cleared.

The usual observed effect of automatic recloser operation is that your power goes out between one and three times, for somewhere around 3-6 seconds each time. In the end, it either comes back on and stays on or, if the fault cannot be cleared, goes off and stays off until the electric utility company can come fix the problem manually.

Comment: Oops - in retrospect, I see someone did mention automatic reclosers earlier. Hopefully my answer provides a little more background / context on their operation.

Comment: No problem. Good to see more people knowledgeable/interested in power systems.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons you might see a temporary voltage dip.

The first (most common) reason is the inrush/starting current of large loads, as mentioned by @David Kessner. It is normal for an industrial three-phase motor to draw **six times rated current** for ten seconds as it starts and runs up to speed. This produces a temporary voltage dip.

.

Another (less common) reason is that there is a **short-circuit "fault"** somewhere on the electricity network, which will depress voltages until the faulty part of the network is isolated. The isolation is automatically performed by fuses (on low-voltage distribution networks) or by protection relays and circuit breakers (on the high-voltage transmission network.)

A typical fault on a local 11kV transmission line, as might be found in a typical Australian suburb, might take anywhere from 200 msec to 2,000 msec to clear. The exact clearing time depends on the kind of protective device in use (fuses or time-delayed relays) and the adjustable time delay settings.

On rural overhead lines it's also common to use auto-reclosers, which are circuit breakers that open if they detect a fault, the re-energise the line after a few seconds. The principle here is that most overhead line faults are temporary (tree branch, etc.) so the fault will not reoccur.

A typical fault on a massive 132kV transmission line typically gets cleared in less than 200 msec. (Any more than this and the power stations will not be able to recover from the fault.)

.

> I can't imaging what could cause such a short event. I mean if someone wants to **open a switch on a substation** (or somewhere else in the grid) they do it for some service operation that takes time, so it doesn't make sense to have an outage shorter than several dozen seconds.

As far as this goes, all substations (in Australia) are designed so there are at least two different switches that can be used to feed each transmission line. Switching operations are nearly always done "make before break" so that service is not interrupted during routine operations or maintenance - so this isn't the source of the voltage dips you describe.